# Python socket check list of server to see if port open

Tags: python-3.x

My function accepts a list of ldpa servers and checks if port 389 is listening on list of servers

Read and reviewed example on python socket but still not doing what i expect.

```py
        def check_server_ldap_port_open(self, domain_controller: list):
        """ check if LDAP port 389 is listening on list of domain controller and returns the first DC listening in list """

        s = socket.socket()
        i = 0

        print('DC', domain_controller)
        while i < len(domain_controller):
            print(i)

            try:
                print('dc#',i ,domain_controller[i])
                s.settimeout(2)
                result_s = s.connect_ex((domain_controller[i], LDAP_PORT_NUMBER))
                print('result_s', result_s)

                if result_s == 0:
                    print('dc', domain_controller[i])
                    return domain_controller[i]
            except socket.error as err:
                raise err
            finally:
                i += 1
                s.close()
```

From testing my function on windows 10 desktop, if it checks a server where port 389 is not listening, it moves on to the next server in the list. But i get the following error below. I always get this error if the first server it receives to check the port is not listening. If I receive a different server where ldap 389 is listening, it works as expected.

I get this error only when the first server to be check is not listening on 389 and it goes to check next server but get WinError 10038. From my search online, its because i'm using windows, but would like confirmation and if theres a work around?

```
DC ['ProblemSRV.abc.domain.', 'GoodSRV1.abc.domain.', 'GoodSRV2.abc.domain.']
0
dc# 0 ProblemSRV.abc.domain.
result_s 10035
1
dc# 1 GoodSRV1.abc.domain.
[2019-08-14 13:25:53,755] ERROR in app: Exception on /v1/nas/app_share/UK/DATA-PRD/ABC\user1/ABC\user2/ [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py", line 313, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\resource.py", line 44, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workspace\api\core\decorators.py", line 79, in wrapper
    return _function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workspace\api\nas\controllers\nas.py", line 93, in post
    my_nas_share = NasShare(country, share_name, primary_owner, secondary_owner, dept_mailbox, trigram)
  File "D:\workspace\api\nas\models\nas.py", line 82, in __init__
    if not self.check_dept_mailbox(dept_mailbox):
  File "D:\workspace\api\nas\models\nas.py", line 414, in check_dept_mailbox
    domain_controller = self.check_server_ldap_port_open(hermes_dc_list)
  File "D:\workspace\api\nas\models\nas.py", line 356, in check_server_ldap_port_open
    raise err
  File "D:\workspace\api\nas\models\nas.py", line 348, in check_server_ldap_port_open
    s.settimeout(2)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: Have you tried using *try: except: finally:* to catch the errors?

Comment: Update code block with try except finally and added console output showing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the fact that your `socket`, `s`, is created at the start of the function.  Later on in your code, you close the socket, and then in the next iteration try to change the timeout.  Python cannot do this because it is closed, so is no longer a socket.  Instead, put `s = socket.socket()` at the start of each loop, and then it is recreated.

The reason why the `try … catch … finally` doesn't work is because when you catch the exception, you re-raise it with `raise err`, so the error still occurs.  Instead you could use it to ignore the error, and move on to the next iteration.  Having said that, the error handling shouldn't be necessary with the new code, as it no longer causes any errors.

Some other changes I made are to change the `while` loop to a `for` loop so you don't have to increment `i` yourself, and I put `s.close()` as soon as you have your result, so that your socket isn't left open if you find a server that is listening. (It **shouldn't** matter as Python does have garbage collection, but it's good practice...)

Full listing:

```
def check_server_ldap_port_open(self, domain_controller: list):
    """ check if LDAP port 389 is listening on list of domain controller and returns the first DC listening in list """

    for i in range(len(domain_controller)):

        s = socket.socket()
        s.settimeout(2)

        result_s = s.connect_ex((domain_controller[i], LDAP_PORT_NUMBER))

        s.close()

        if result_s == 0:
            return domain_controller[i]
```